# Is it "call us at 181" or "call us on 181"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if I have to use *on* or *at* when talking about calling a particular number? For example:

> If you need help with your phone, call us **at**/**on** 181.

Are both perfectly natural and correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK we usually 'call (someone) **on** a phone number', but in the US and other countries, people may use '**a**t'.

[At or on a phone number](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english/linguistics/1268047-at-on-the-telephone-number.html)